# how to reference cordova.js in index.html

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am adding plugins to my cordova android application but I am unable to reference cordova.js file in the index.html page. Image of Structure of my application is : [App structure Image][1]. I have highlight both files in the image index.html and cordova.js. The solution I though was to copy the plugin JS files from **platform_www** folder to inside **www** folder. But as the plugins keeps on adding its seems not a good solution to copy paste js files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the cordova.js file gets copied into the www directory structure when the app is compiled, you don't need to manually copy it - you just add a link:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```